# Jquery serializeArray break then continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, serializearray

I'm really new to using serializeArray in jQuery so please forgive me if i'm not asking the correct question.

I have a form which on click add the data to fields within a div ID which works fine, it keeps adding data each time i click which is great, however is it possible to split each form's results? For example, you type in a name and phone number, click add, then in the div ID #results it adds the data then i want the next time you add data, it add's it to the same div ID but seperated by a box

```
$("#saveAndAdd").click(function(){
  addTrip();
var x = $(".cool-test").serializeArray();
  $.each(x, function(i, field){
    $("#results").append(field.value + " " );
  });
});
function addTrip() {
var providerName = $("#providerName").val();
var providerPhone = $("#providerPhone").val();
    $("#providerTypeValue").html(providerType);
$("#providerNameValue").html(providerName);
$("#providerPhoneValue").html(providerPhone);

<label class="uikit-text-input__label" for="Input field">Name</label>
              <input class="uikit-text-input input-half" name="Input field" id="providerName" type="text" value="" aria-required="true">
            <label class="uikit-text-input__label" for="Input field">Phone</label>
              <input class="uikit-text-input input-half" name="Input field" id="providerPhone" type="text" value="" aria-required="true">
```

Comment: It is hard to follow this question.  Can I suggest that you provide a complete example which displays the issue? See [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for assistance. There appears to be both javascript and html missing.

Comment: Sorry steve0, i just realised yeah it cut a lot out, i've added the code in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/H1tman/n2p1rufw/4/